# Is the bracha for wild and cultivated blueberries both Haetz?

Tags: blessing

I found out through work that wild blueberries grow on very low bushes and was curious if it impacts the bracha. Do they still qualify for haetz blessing?

Their height, "The two primary species of wild blueberries that grow in North America are the lowbush blueberry (Vaccinium angustifolium) and the sour top (Vaccinium myrtilloides). The sour top is a larger shrub, reaching heights of 6 to 24 inches tall, while the lowbush blueberry grows 3 to 15 inches high." https://www.hunker.com/12339653/what-do-wild-blueberry-bushes-look-like

vs cultivated blueberries that come from highbush, "highbush blueberry (Vaccinium corymbosum) grows between 6 and 12 feet tall". https://www.hunker.com/13426685/how-tall-do-blueberry-bushes-grow

Thanks in advance!